# MongoDB php: find when element is present inside array

Tags: php-mongodb

I have following document structure

```
{
  "_id":12638gkhF67JKGftyh88,
  "tags":[1,3,5,6,9]
}
.
.
.
```

I want to search search on the basis where _id matches and tags has value '6'

in PHP, my query will be like

```
$collection -> find(
  '$and' => array(
     array("_id" => new MongoId("12638gkhF67JKGftyh88")),
     array("tags" => WHAT WOULD BE HERE)
  )
)
```

I couldn't find anything about this, help me out plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the in operator

```
$collection -> find(
'$and' => array(
 array("_id" => new MongoId("12638gkhF67JKGftyh88")),
 array("tags" => array("$in" => "6"))
)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

in mongodb there is an operator of in for searching values in arrays - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/